# AMPScript Editor

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, content-builder

I am brand new to Marketing Cloud and AMPScript in general, but I come from a .NET Razor/MVC background and am used to working in an editor like Visual Studio or Sublime. Has anyone had any success using an external editor to edit AMPScript text for emails (from Content Builder)? I have tried both Visual Studio Code and Notepad++, but their syntax extensions for AMPScript are very basic and don't offer much advantage to working within the browser.

My intent here is to avoid making this a question about personal favorites, I simply want to know if anyone has found ANY editor that works well. I apologize if there is a similar question on here, but I could not find anything on the Salesforce Stack Exchange using the main search function. I have also searched Google for an answer, and have browsed the Salesforce forums and documentation, but I have yet to find a practical answer from a Salesforce developer.

If this question is found to be a duplicate or in violation of this SE subsite, I will gladly remove the question. Thank you in advance for any guidance that is provided.

Comment: I should add that my company is currently still using the "Classic Content" editor for emails, but plans to slowly transition to Content Builder.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that most of these editors existed far before ContentBuilders time and a community owned. Our kind benefactors have chosen not to update it (to be frank everyone should pitch it to keeping them up to date).

Visual Code works ok, but if you want something inline, in browser, I would suggest this [chrome plug in](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-marketing-clou/fkmojdpmdmdmeohmebiejjclmegkalli?hl=en). It's by no way a panacea, but hope it helps

Comment: My goal is to avoid using the browser for any editing, but I will give the plug-in a try. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: I installed the plug-in, but was unable to get it to work properly in the Classic Content editor.

Answer (score 1):

Chek out https://ampscript.io/ - it does not only highlight the code, but it also check some basic syntax rules related to:

- opening and closing of AMPscript blocks and in-line AMPscript,
- syntax of conditional statements,
- syntax of loops,
- syntax of AMPscript functions,
- and other things such as checking of parentheses match; if all variables have been set, etc

It's a community initiative and completely free to use.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sublime Text's AMPScript package works well for me. I just copy from MC editor and paste in Sublime and then set the syntax to AMPScript.

https://packagecontrol.io/packages/AMPScript